# AWS, DigitalOcean vs heroku, google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, heroku, amazon-web-services, web-hosting

The difference between the AWS, DigitalOean and heroku and google app engine?

AWS and DigitalOcean are web hosting site used to host simple dynamic sites where as the heroku and google app engine is used to deploy complex web applications?

AWS is Iaas and heroku is Paas, it would be great if you could give me a real time example.

This question shows inexperience , please do bare.

Comment: Definitely helpful to me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

tldr;

- **DigitalOcean** is a "cloud" VPS provider. You get your usual VPS server from them.
- **AWS** is a full blown cloud provider with services that allow you to actually build a complete datacentre (the options are mindblowing).
- **Heroku** allows you to quickly publish web apps by pushing your code up to a git repository (they offer an abstraction layer). Trouble-free POC heaven!
- **Google App Engine** is a service similar in a sense to Heroku (different features, however).

Comment: I understand now. So heroku does not provide hosting(obviously), but it requires a service like AWS for the app to be used in a particular website?

Comment: All of the host your code/webapp/whatever. The difference is to the level of control you have on the underlying box. For example, DO and AWS will give you SSH root access for a Linux box. Heroku and Google App Engine limit your access and you have a set of command line tools / web interfaces through which you tweak setting while they automate everything on the background. That said, Heroku /does/ host your app and that's why you're paying them :)

Comment: Again, it comes down to what sort of control you need over the infrastructure that your app runs on. It's completely personal preference whether you choose to worry for nothing but your code or have fine-grained access to the last detail on your server. Give them a spin, most of them offer some sort of trial.

Comment: That was very helpful.I do not have any previous experience at all.I am planning to first start a blog.I decided to use GHOST blog and do it, and use DO, since Do has ghost option in them which takes care of the full backend I suppose. What I want to know is, what is the difference between a DO and a normal hostgator type webhosting?

Comment: I have heard about them using Cpanel, then what does cloud hosting providers like DO and AWS use? The process of uploading the static  and scripts are the same like how we used to do in a normal web hosting site(cpanel).I mainly want to know the implementation process in a normal web host providers and cloud providers and the diff?